# html + php upload form is not uploading the file

Tags: php, html

I am currently trying to debug why my PHP script isn't currently working.  Essentially, I have a web form that end user creates new group name, then has the option to upload 1 of 2 different files.

html:

```
<form method="post" action="/php/create.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="customerName">Customer Name:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="foldername" name="foldername" placeholder="Customer Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="healthCheckOutput">HealthCheck Results</label>
<input type="file" id="healthCheckFile">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="SANUpload">Appliance Data</label>
<input type="file" id="SANUpload" name="SANUpload">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

php:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
//Create Customer Folder
$folder = $_POST['foldername'];

$dirPath = '../customers/'.$folder;
if (!mkdir($dirPath, 0750, true)) {
    die('Failed to create customer folders...current customer name already exists');
}

//Upload the file and move it to the correct folders for processing
//$target_dir = "/uploads/";
//$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["SANUpload"]["name"])

$uploaddir = "uploads/";
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['SANUpload']['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['SANUpload']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)){
echo "Success.\n";
} else {
echo "Failure.\n";
}

echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);
print "</pre>";
?>
```

debug from PHP:

```
Warning:  move_uploaded_file(uploads/test2.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/php/create.php on line 26

Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/php8E2y8j' to 'uploads/test2.csv' in /var/www/html/php/create.php on line 26

Failure.
Here is some more debugging info:Array
(
[SANUpload] => Array
    (
        [name] => test2.csv
        [type] => text/csv
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/php8E2y8j
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 58242
    )

)
```

I am sure its something simple that i am not doing.  Keep in mind this is not a public facing application its a small local host virtual appliance.

Comment: try upload a file to some folder already created

Comment: It's complaining that the `uploads` directory doesn't exist. Is the `uploads` directory a subdirectory of the folder containing the script, or is it somewhere else? Try using the full path.

Comment: its a folder under root.  even if i put the full path in i still get that error.  I can try and move it.  but to @Barmar point the file exists and is there and writeable - the script isn't detecting it.  I haven't been able to figure out what i am missing.

Comment: Have you tried changing to `$uploaddir = "/uploads/";`? Does the user have permissions to write into that directory?

Comment: same error as before line 26 is causing an issue or throwing the error.  `if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['SANUpload']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Success.\n";
} else {
    echo "Failure.\n";
}`

Comment: Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpjxikxf' to '/uploads/test2.csv' in /var/www/html/php/create.php on line 26

Comment: just for grins i checked the php.ini to make sure it was set to /var/www/html/tmp as the upload tmp directory.

Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/var/www/html/tmp/phpOyToRY' to '/uploads/test2.csv' in /var/www/html/php/create.php on line 26

Comment: The target pathname is not interpreted relative to the web root, it's a pathname in the regular filesystem. So it may need to be something like `/var/www/uploads/` or `/var/www/html/uploads/`. But usually you want to copy it to somewhere outside the webroot, so people can't access it directly with a URL, they have to use a download script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found online a better more detailed example of the upload process for PHP.   This in turn helped solve the issue.

This is what I am using now - works perfectly.

PHP:

```
define("UPLOAD_DIR", "/var/www/html/uploads/");

if (!empty($_FILES["SANUpload"])) {
$myFile = $_FILES["SANUpload"];

if ($myFile["error"] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    echo "<p>An error occurred.</p>";
    exit;
}

// ensure a safe filename
$name = preg_replace("/[^A-Z0-9._-]/i", "_", $myFile["name"]);

// don't overwrite an existing file
$i = 0;
$parts = pathinfo($name);
while (file_exists(UPLOAD_DIR . $name)) {
    $i++;
    $name = $parts["filename"] . "-" . $i . "." . $parts["extension"];
}

// preserve file from temporary directory
$success = move_uploaded_file($myFile["tmp_name"],
    UPLOAD_DIR . $name);
if (!$success) { 
    echo "<p>Unable to save file.</p>";
    exit;
}
// set proper permissions on the new file
chmod(UPLOAD_DIR . $name, 0644);
}
```

This is in conjunction with what i have already setup with the HTML.
Found this which went into detail and had a very much working copy documented.

http://www.sitepoint.com/file-uploads-with-php/